# How to put focus from UIWebView onto Another UIView during a long press

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiview, uiwebview, focus

I use javascript to detect long press(**a touchstart event then rare touchmove events in 300ms will be esteemed as a long press, which doesn't require a touchend**),then use javascript

```
document.location = "XXXXXXX";
```

to send out the notification to the upper UIView.I guarantee there is no problem in the js code.

Problem comes here: Then in the delegate I wrote

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
/*
blablabla
*/
//show Contextual Menu
[webView resignFirstResponder];
CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
ContextualMenu *menu = [[ContextualMenu alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
[menu becomeFirstResponder];
/*
blablabla
*/
return NO;}
```

Some part of the ContextualMenu *menu view is half transparent so I can see:

**When I start a Long Press in the UIWebView and ContextualMenu's View comes out and covers the UIWebView,My finger can still scroll the UIWebView**(until I lift my finger from the screen)

Is there any way to stop that behavier and **move the focus from UIWebView To the ContextualMenu view** as ContextualMenu shows up?(Ignoring the going-on long press gesture)

UPDATE:

I added these code before and after JS send the notifiction to the upper UIView, but still no use.(also tried trigger touchcancel event)

```
$(event.target).trigger('touchend');
$(event.currentTarget).trigger('touchend');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it in a complicated way. I subclassed UIWindow and overload sendEvent: method, according to this article http://atastypixel.com/blog/a-trick-for-capturing-all-touch-input-for-the-duration-of-a-touch/ .Besides, I had to make a bit modification to that code: enumerate the views array to choose the right view when dispatching touchMoved event.
Meanwhile, I replaced the javascript code with a UILongPressGestureRecognizer added to the UIWebView, so it seemed neater.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to set userInteractionEnabled of UIWebView to False?

Comment: I added webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO; to the delegate function but still no use:(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var el = ...
el.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
  ...
  ...
  **e.preventDefault();**
}, false);
```

Good luck!

Comment: this do stop the scrolling in the UIWebView :), but it doesn't hand the focus to the ContextualMenu view :(